# DFS: Error creating domain-based namespace "The namespace cannot be queried. The RPC server is unavailable."

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I try to create a domain-based namespace but when I hit "next" on the "choose type wizard page" I get the message:

> The namespace cannot be queried. The RPC server is unavailable.

I found one [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021914) regarding this problem, and indeed the DNS resolution of the DomainDNSName was flawed. But although I fixed this DNS issue, I still get this message.

A stand-alone namespace can be created.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Is it possible that this is related to the fact that I'm using a single-lable domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be due to many issues including:

- network filtering
- DNS misconfiguration
- AD sites misconfiguration
- LDAP corruption
- clock-skew

Unfortunately, there are many many possible issues that could cause this problem. Try out some of microsoft's troubleshooting tools such as repadmin to make sure your AD topology is sound before implementing advanced features like DFS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I won't use DFS I won't do any further investigation. (Everything else is running fine...)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where the DFS server lost connection to the DC. I found the DFS Namespace service (DFS) wasn't running, and restarting the service fixed the issue.